# Is any software/product operated under a name a business?

Tags: software, business, tax-law

If make an app and publish that I alone operate under a made up name, am I legally a business or an individual?

Comment: To the IRS, you're both... Depending on how you register that fictitious name, you're either a business, an individual, a DBA, or nothing at all. If you just make up a name and don't register it, you are technically operating as an individual. This also depends on where you are. How are you registering it? Where are you located?

Comment: Depends on your jurisdiction.

Answer (score 1):

### [Legal personhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_person)

To have standing under the law you have to be a person - individuals (among other things) are people; businesses are not. For an analogy - a football club is (probably) a legal person; a game of football isn't.

Things that are legal people include:

- natural persons;
- corporations and companies;
- governments;
- some supra-national organisations;
- The Whanganui River in New Zealand and the Ganges River in India.

You are free to call yourself whatever you like - most legal systems accept that your name is whatever you are known as. If you sell your software then you are you running a business selling software.

Comment: What about ad based software or freemium and completely free software?

Comment: Te Urewera is also a legal person (http://www.legislation.govt.nz/act/public/2014/0051/latest/whole.html#DLM6183705).

Answer (score 0):

The post is tagged "taxes" so I'll address it from a tax perspective.

Generally, activities conducted for profit by an individual who has not formed an entity such as a corporation or a limited liability company are taxed in one of two ways (which often are indistinguishable in tax outcome by not always).

Sometimes they are treated as a kind of business called a "sole proprietorship". In this case the income and expenses of the business are determined in accordance with tax rules and the proprietor (you) are taxed on the profit as income.

Sometimes the activity is taxed as investment income as a private person. In this case, the revenues are income to you for income tax purposes, but the expenses related to the activity are not always allowed as deductions.

The fact that some activity is not a business does not mean that income from it is tax free. Usually, the tax treatment that arises if your activity is not a business is worse and not better.

But, some business regulations apply to sole proprietorships but not to mere investment activities of individuals.

The rules for determining which regime applies for tax purposes vary considerably from jurisdiction to jurisdiction.